# Output and count total number of occurrences using grep in linux/nix

Tags: linux, unix, command

I have a data file ( users.dat) with entries like:

```
user1
user2
user4
user1
user2
user1
user4
...
user3
user2
```

which command I should ( grep? wc?) use to count how many times each word repeats and output it to user_total.dat like this:

```
user1 80
user2 35
user3 18
user4 120
```

the issue is that I cannot specify "user1" or "user19287" because there are too many users with random, but repeating numbers.

But there are repeating users in that DAT file.

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `uniq` command to count the repetitions of a line. It requires the input to be sorted, so use `sort` first.

```
sort users.dat | uniq -c > user_total.dat
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sort <users.dat | uniq -c > user_total.dat
```

If you want it further in order of occurance pass it through sort a 2nd time using some form the -n argument (read man page on that).

(on edit: bah... didn't realize how dumb the system rendered that bit of code)

Comment: Where are you counting the duplicates?

Comment: Apparently (and I didn't notice this when I posted) the system deleted everything from the pipe symbol over.  Sigh.  Error in using Stack Exchange, not my UN*X skillz.

Comment: It's because you forgot to use code markup, so the `<` and `>` characters were taken as HTML markup.